# How to change the element position?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

In my browsers Firefox and Chrome I don't get any errors or warnings.  It's just practice. I'm taking a course in javascript and Dynamic HTML. If anybody cares to look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it. There's got to be something that I'm not getting right.

I want to create new divs as the page loads. These divs will appear as an ordered group that changes depending upon external data from a JSON file. I will need to do this with a for a loop because there are over 100 divs needed.

[image: demo]

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div id="showFilters">
        <!-- GROUP -->
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center mt-4">
        <p>Add new group</p>
        <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $('#addFilter').click(function () {
        count++;
        let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
            '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="name">Name</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="latin">Latin</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="latin" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][latin]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="field">Select a field</label>'+
            '<select id="field" class="form-select" name="filters['+count+'][field]">'+
            '<option value="1">CheckBox</option>'+
            '<option value="2">Color</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="showGroups"> '+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="w-100 text-center">'+
            '<p>Add new subgroup.</p>'+
            '<a onclick="addChildFilter()" class="bg-danger text-info pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">'+
            '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>'+
            '</a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        $('#showFilters').append(html);
    });
    function addChildFilter() {
        count++;
        let selectedField = $('#field').val();
        if (selectedField == 1) {
            let html = '<div class="w-100">'+
                '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 position-relative">'+
                '<label for="name">Check Box Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#showGroups').append(html);
        }
        if (selectedField == 2) {
            let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="name">Color Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="code">Code Color</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters['+count+'][code]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            $('#showGroups').append(html);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Rana, I ypdated my post

Comment: Yes. This is all the code of this photo you see.

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel I had to add jquery and font awesome libs to work but it seems to be working fine for me.
https://jsbin.com/pefusahaci/edit

Comment: I think it does not work.

Comment: @Rana, I updated my post...

Comment: Yes, I want to when clicking on `+`, The `div` own div putting.

Comment: @Rana, I updated my post...  & Can you answer this question?

Comment: Can you tell about what you want to do with `red` and `blue` `+` sign as it is not clear from image , and plz use English language in your code as it is not understandable

Comment: @Rana, I updated my post...

Comment: Also clear what you want to do with `blue` `+` sign and `red` `+` sign

Comment: @Rana, I updated my post...

Comment: The reason of this behavior is `$('#showGroups').append(html)` as you are appending to an `id` the function will check where is that `id` first occur so wherever that `id` occurred first the fields will be added there only

Comment: Here is large code so it will be hard for you too to debug or come to solution , so at start take small code and `append` it (like 2 fields on new group 1 field on new subgroup)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put `this` in the `onclick` event so it will be added into that element only like this :

`<a onclick="addChildFilter(this)"`
then
`function addChildFilter(reed){}`
and then
`reed.parentElement.append(html);`

This way it is adding to the place where `add subgroup` btn is present . The problem here now is that the `html` code is printed directly not the fields as you know jQuery you may find the problem as I am not good in jQuery (so used some JavaScript) . See if you can and find help from this answer.

```js
let count = 0;
    $('#addFilter').click(function () {
        count++;
        let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
            '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="name">Name</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="latin">Latin</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="latin" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][latin]">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">'+
            '<label for="field">Select a field</label>'+
            '<select id="field" class="form-select" name="filters['+count+'][field]">'+
            '<option value="1">CheckBox</option>'+
            '<option value="2">Color</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="showGroups"> '+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="w-100 text-center">'+
            '<p>Add new subgroup.</p>'+
            '<a onclick="addChildFilter(this)" class="bg-danger text-info pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">'+
            '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>'+
            '</a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        $('#showFilters').append(html);
    });
    function addChildFilter(reed) {
        count++;
        let selectedField = $('#field').val();
        if (selectedField == 1) {
            let html = '<div class="w-100">'+
                '<div class="col-md-4 mb-3 position-relative">'+
                '<label for="name">Check Box Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            reed.parentElement.append(html);
        }
        if (selectedField == 2) {
            let html = '<div class="position-relative">'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="name">Color Name</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="filters['+count+'][name]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">'+
                '<label for="code">Code Color</label>'+
                '<input type="text" id="code" class="form-control jscolor" name="filters['+count+'][code]">'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            reed.parentElement.append(html);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div id="showFilters">
      <!-- GROUP -->
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center mt-4">
      <p>Add new group</p>
      <a id="addFilter" class="bg-primary text-white pt-2 pb-2 pe-3 ps-3 rounded-circle cursor-pointer">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```